# Unable to delete API testapi. There is a chance it was deleted, please try to refresh

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-management

I'm new to azure and previously I have used GCP and it give very clear errors info but with Azure Cloud it just shows a message that something went wrong and no clear info.

I have created an API on `API Management` and trying to delete that API. and whenever I delete, It just shows me `Unable to delete API testapi. There is a chance it was deleted, please try to refresh.`

And API never gets deleted. I have all required permission for this resource, in fact I'm `owner` of the resource. So clearly, there is no problem with permission.

Also I'm unable to create an API using OpenAPI specification. The API that I have created was blank API. When I use OpenAPI it says `Could not create an API. Please try again later.`

Can anyone advise if I'm doing anything wrong or it requires access to more Azure resource to perform this action?

Comment: Try deleting the APIM Service and re-create if you do not have any other APIs in it because it might be due to Network Issue or issue in the APIM Service creation/provisioning.

Comment: @Hasher I think so. Also I'm unable to create an API using OpenAPI specification. The API that I have created was blank API. When I use OpenAPI it says `Could not create an API. Please try again later.`

Comment: Whatever the API type (blank API or Function API or Open API), check if you have enabled the [Soft delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/soft-delete#supporting-interfaces) on azure apim service because there is a process of doing the operation on the APIs if that APIM is enabled with Soft-delete that has given in the documentation

Comment: For this issue (`Could not create an API. Please try again later`), it might be browser issue - do hard refresh or restart and check the internet connection also because APIM Service provisioning takes hardly minimum >30 minutes and can take more based on the internet speed and can occur interruptions in provisioning if proper internet connection is not passed.

Comment: @Hasher I think the soft-delete is for applying an option for recovering any deleted APIs within a time range. In our case, I just need to delete it.

Comment: By any chance, your API Management instance is in Provisioning state? Check once if the status of the APIM instance is showing "Online" .

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin Yes. It's showing online

Comment: Then check by deleting existing APIM Service and try creating new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after trying all methods, I have an answer. Hasher's solution worked.

I Deleted and created again APIM service and it worked for me.